# How safe is it to store your database in /var/lib/docker/volumes/?

Tags: mysql, docker

At the moment my configuration for MySQL database is as follows:

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.7.22
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
    - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Basically my database is stored in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`. But how safe is it? Is it fine for production? It seems that `docker-compose down` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) should remove the database even though it doesn't in my case. But still, it seems slightly dangerous. What are the alternatives? Create folder manually and link the volume to the manually created folder? But in that case every other developer in the team will have to create that folder.

Comment: Good question. I've wondered about it. I would think we also need to consider disk replication, and backups on it.

Comment: Wondering about the word "safe". Are you concerned about security (unauthorized access), or data loss, data integrity?

Comment: looks like `docker-compose down --volumes` destroys it, but can prevented with [external](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image#external)

Comment: It doesn't remove the volume unless you use `docker-compose down -v`. Also it's better to not use `docker-compose` for production but rather use docker swarm and `docker stack deploy`. In that case you have to use contraints to ensure your service runs on the same node as your named volume, or use a  volume driver that is multi-host aware.

Comment: @TheImpaler Data loss.

Comment: Depending on how big the db can potentially get, could also be a concern if it causes the VM to run out of space. Docker really hates when it's VM runs out of space, and will randomly (but frequently) crash the docker daemon, which can cause data loss in several places. I personally use a separate mysql container, and mount a folder on the host to that container, and store the db files on the host.